Find functions $u_n\to u$ such that $\int u_n=20$ and $\int u=25$

Find a sequence of functions $u_n$, such that $u_n$ converges pointwise to a function $u$ belonging to $L^1(\lambda)$, and that
$$
\int u \, d\lambda = 25,
$$
$$
\int u_n \, d\lambda = 20
$$
for all $n$.

I've received the following hint.
$$
u_n = a_n 1_{A_n} + b_n 1_{B_n}
$$
for suitable $a_n, b_n \in \mathbb{R}$ and $A_n, B_n \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$.
I've tried to use $u_n=\frac{25}{n}{1}_{(0,n)}-5\cdot{1}_{(n,n+1)}$, which on paper seems good at the $n$ cancels the $n$ and $(n,n+1)$ goes to infinity, but the limit function goes to $0$. What could I use instead?

Hi, welcome to Math SE. Hint: what is $\int_{-\infty}^\infty\lim_{n\to\infty}n^{-p}1_{(x_0,,x_0+n^p)}(x)dx$ for $p>0$, $p=0$ & $p<0$?

Could you elaborate further? I don't see the resemblance with my idea, but i'm trying to understand yours. Is the sequence of functions $n^{-p}$ for some p?

My hint is that the integrand is $0$ for $p\ne0$ (the reasons why depend on the sign of $p$), but if $p=0$ the integral is $1$.

But how is this used? If the integral is 1, i get that $a_n$ could be 25, but how do i control $p$?

Your first attempt had a term with $x_0=0,,p=1$. You came close to my $p=0$ idea with another term, but your equivalent of $x_0$ was $n$ rather than a constant.

But how does this apply to the problem? The limit function still goes to zero, which is the same problem i have with my original function.

Not when $p=0$. Take$$u_n=25\cdot1_{(0,,1)}-5n\cdot1_{(1,,1+1/n)}.$$

Please don't delete or significantly change questions after they have received an answer. I've rolled back your last edit replacing the question body with essentially nothing.

You were on the right track! Try$$u_n=25\cdot{\bf 1}_{(a,b)}-5\cdot{\bf 1}_{(n,n+1)},$$
for any fixed $a,b\in\Bbb R$ such that $b-a=1$.
Then, $\int u_n=25-5=20$, and for all $x\in\Bbb R$, $$u_n(x)\to u(x):=25\cdot{\bf 1}_{(a,b)}(x).$$

Thanks Anne! I've also tried this setup, but with $1_{(0,1)}$. Could you explain why it works with $(-1,0)$?. And does this converge pointwise for all $x$? If $x=2$, then the first indicator is 0, right?
